# Unable to load some native node js modules with electron 4.0.6 on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, native-module

I am trying to upgrade my application from electron 1.8.1 to 4.0.6. I am using multiple native node js modules. They all compile successfully (or prebuilt binaries are available).

I am getting following error when requiring one of the modules.

```
XXXX\node_modules\electron-log\renderer.js:34 [10:14:51.109] Failed to add 
module. Error: Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
\?\XXXXX\node_modules\pc-ble-driver-js\build\Release\pc-ble-driver-js- 
 sd_api_v2.node
```

Whereas other native modules (such as serialport, noble-uwp) are loading and working fine.

This error generally indicates that a required DLL is missing. I have used Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the dependencies but I couldn't nail down the error. I tried to compare dependencies for module that works and the one for which I get above error. I didn't see obvious differences.

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. I also have VC++ 2015 redistributable installed.

My electron specific dependencies are:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "~4.0.6",
    "electron-builder": "~20.39.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4"
},
```

I am using node-js 10.15.3.

I have noticed that till electron 3, node_modules/electron/dist had many DLLs present. These DLLs are not present with electron 4.

Are any additional dependencies needed to be installed for native modules to work with electron 4?

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work.

For native node js modules to work with electron 4 on Windows, it needs to be compiled with "Delay Load Hook". More info: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#a-note-about-win_delay_load_hook and https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/269#issuecomment-455580129. After making these changes my failing module started to work.

About why other modules worked without these changes is because they use node-gyp directly. It takes care of using this hook.

My failing module uses cmake-js, which needs above mentioned additional changes.