# Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed on electron but it's fine on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, windows-10, d

I'm trying to load a custom module in electron written in D with [`node_dlang`](https://code.dlang.org/packages/node_dlang) package, which is fine with node, but it fails within electron.

the test with node, that runs just fine, goes like this:

```
const nativeModule = require('./module.node');
const assert = require('assert');

assert(nativeModule != null);
assert(nativeModule.ultimate() == 42);
```

But when I went to use it within electron.js, through the preload script, it returns in an error.

the preload script goes like this:

```
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

const nativeModule = require('./module.node');
const assert = require('assert');

assert(nativeModule.ultimate() == 42);

function pageLoaded()
{
   // ...
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', pageLoaded);
```

the error when I attempt to load the module within electron application is:

> A JavaScript error occured in the browser process
> --------------------------- Uncaught Exception: Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> ```
> \\?\C:\Users\001\Desktop\ele\module.node
>     at process.func [as dlopen] (VM70 asar_bundle.js:5)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..node (VM43 loader.js:1138)
>     at Object.func [as .node] (VM70 asar_bundle.js:5)
>     at Module.load (VM43 loader.js:935)
>     at Module._load (VM43 loader.js:776)
>     at Function.f._load (VM70 asar_bundle.js:5)
>     at Function.o._load (VM75 renderer_init.js:33)
>     at Module.require (VM43 loader.js:959)
>     at require (VM50 helpers.js:88)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (VM88 C:\Users\001\Desktop\ele\preload.js:6)
> ```

What's causing this and how do I fix this?

**version**

```
node version is: v14.17.0
electron.js: v13.1.1
```

both are 64-bit.

the module source code goes like this:

```
import std.stdio : stderr;
import node_dlang;

extern(C):

void atStart(napi_env env)
{
    import std.stdio;
    writeln ("Hello from D!");
}

int ultimate()
{
    return 42;
}

mixin exportToJs! (ultimate, MainFunction!atStart);
```

it's compiled with `dub` command line. No arguments.

**UPDATE 1** Do I need to rebuild this module? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029955/electron-uncaught-error-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-fai) but it didn't work for me either. I installed the electron-rebuild package by `npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild` and rebuild with `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd -v 13.1.1` the command ran fine but I still got same error.

**UPDATE 2:** inside the console, I clicked in the javascript source code file link in the error message (from the exception) it points to this line of code, where there's this comment saying that:

> no static exports found

[image]

what does that mean? is this related to the methods in D class? they're marked as public... not sure if related

Comment: My guess is that the dll's made by that extension do not support multiple initialization by default. See [this](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_context_aware_addons). The best option here would probably be opening an issue on [`node_dlang` github page](https://github.com/NotSpooky/node_dlang).

Comment: Actually, no, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55333503/9731532). Probably because of that, I'm not able to load the dll even from the main file.

Answer (score 0):

Electron is a Windows-Application and therefore you need to remove output to std. Try to remove

```
import std.stdio : stderr;
```

and

```
import std.stdio;
writeln ("Hello from D!");
```

and retry import to Electron.

Comment: I've tried this one before, didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74280836/9558119) post from me regarding same. Since it is electron build might be missing Visual C++ Build Environment: Visual Studio Build Tools